# get man page for c function not system command

Tags: c, linux, manpage

I want to type "`man time`" and info about the `time.h` time function, but instead I am getting the linux time system command.

`man time 2` or `man time 3` doesn't do any different. How can I find the right man page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `man man`? Then you would find out that `man 3 time` works.

Comment: Or if in doubt, use `man -a time` and step through all of them.

Comment: I did do man man, but I thought I saw the order as man <item> <section>, got it cleared up later